# comparing string to .txt file from website android

Tags: android, gps, location

Hi I'm building an app that pulls my address using gps and then compares it to an address i saved to a .txt file in a website. It pulls the .txt file fine. Then the gps gets lat and long fine and also reverse geocodes fine. I typed the txt perfect I put the two textviews right on top of each other using a relative layout to see if I could find a difference. I've also thought maybe, the web files are not text at this point but maybe some kind of xml so I converted it to a string put them in another textview and then compared those two as strings and still it will not show them as a match.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button compareButton;
Button addressButton;
TextView locationText;
TextView addressText;
TextView internetText;
TextView addressText2;
TextView internetText2;
Location currentLocation;
double currentLatitude;
double currentLongitude;
int webCounter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();

    addressText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.addressText);
    locationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationText);
    addressButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addressButton);
    compareButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.compareButton);
    addressText2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.addressText2);
    internetText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.internetText);
    internetText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.internetText2);
    webCounter = 0;

    changeWebAdress();
    getWebAdress();
    getLatLong();

        this.addressButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                getAddress();
                getWebAdress();
                convertAdress();

            }
        });
        this.compareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                compareAddress();
                getWebAdress();
            }
        }); 
}

void getAddress(){
    try{
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = 
            gcd.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude,100);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++){
                Address address =  addresses.get(i);
                int maxIndex = address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                for (int x = 0; x <= maxIndex; x++ ){
                    result.append(address.getAddressLine(x));
                    result.append(",");
                }               
                result.append(address.getLocality());
                result.append(",");
                result.append(address.getPostalCode());
                result.append("\n\n");
            }
            addressText.setText(result.toString());

        }
      }
    catch(IOException ex){
        addressText.setText(ex.getMessage().toString());
    }
}

void updateLocation(Location location){
    currentLocation = location;
    currentLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
    currentLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
    locationText.setText(""+currentLatitude + ", " + currentLongitude);
}

    private void compareAddress(){

    String adress2;
    String internet2;

    adress2 = addressText2.getText().toString();
    internet2 =internetText2.getText().toString();

    if (adress2.equalsIgnoreCase(internet2)){
        compareButton.setText("like it on FaceBook");
    }

    //else{
        //changeWebAdress();
    //}
}

private void convertAdress(){

    internetText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    addressText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    internetText2.setText(internetText.getText().toString());
    addressText2.setText(addressText.getText().toString());

}

private void changeWebAdress(){

    webCounter = webCounter+1;

    if (webCounter == 100){

        webCounter = 0;

    }


}

private void getWebAdress(){


    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://webAdress"+webCounter+".txt");
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
            HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity buf = null;
            try {
                buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = buf.getContent();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            internetText.setText(total.toString()); 
}

    private void getLatLong(){

        LocationManager locationManager = 
            (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                updateLocation(location); 

            }
            public void onStatusChanged(
                    String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    }
}
```

I do know I need to make the internet collect an asyncTask. I plan on doing that if i can get this functioning. For now I'm running it in strict Mode. The txt file is my address I didn't want it on the internet so i have remove the web address I'm using.

Comment: I think the \n characters might cause your problem, try to delete them from both the server response and the gps data

Comment: that worked, thank you so much, I've been messing with this for 3 days, if you post it as an answer i could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the \n characters might cause your problem, try to delete them from both the server response and the gps data